# How to make the same color scale range for all plots?

Tags: plotting, graphics, color, plot-themes

I would like to make a density plot of a function: $f=B(r^2+z^2)sin^2z$ for some range of parameter B. The color scale for each graph has a different value. For instance, for $B=5: f=600$ is white color, $f=0$ is black color, but for $B=25: f=3000$ is white color, $f=0$ is black color.

How could it be made so that the color scales for all graphs (for each $B$) show the same range of change in the function? For example, the same scale as for the maximum parameter $B$ $(Bmax = 60)$: for B=0 scale range 0-3000, for B=5 scale range 0-3000, for B=10 scale range 0-3000, for B=25 scale range 0-3000.

```
ClearAll["Global`*"]

f[B_] := B*(r^2 + z^2)*Sin[z]^2;

Table[DensityPlot[f[B], {r, 0, 10}, {z, -5, 5}, FrameLabel -> {r, z}, 
  PlotLabel -> "B = " <> ToString[B], ColorFunction -> "SunsetColors",
   PlotPoints -> 250, PlotLegends -> Automatic], {B, {0, 5, 10, 25}}]
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Perhaps something like this? You just need to define the `ColorFunction` and set `ColorFunctionScaling` to `False`. I also adjusted the bar legends (they're all the same now since they're all on the same color scaling).

```
f[B_] := B*(r^2 + z^2)*Sin[z]^2;

Table[DensityPlot[f[B], {r, 0, 10}, {z, -5, 5}, FrameLabel -> {r, z}, 
  PlotLabel -> "B = " <> ToString[B], 
  ColorFunction -> (ColorData["SunsetColors"][#/3000] &), 
  PlotPoints -> 250, 
  PlotLegends -> 
   BarLegend[{ColorData["SunsetColors"][#/3000] &, {0, 3000}}], 
  ColorFunctionScaling -> False], {B, {0, 5, 10, 25}}]
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

```
$Version

(* "13.3.1 for Mac OS X ARM (64-bit) (July 24, 2023)" *)

Clear["Global`*"]

f[r_, B_, z_] := B*(r^2 + z^2)*Sin[z]^2;
```

Determine the range of the function within the region of interest

```
{min, max} = #[{f[r, B, z], 0 <= r <= 10, -5 <= z <= 5, 0 <= B <= 25}, 
  {r, B, z}] & /@ {NMinValue, NMaxValue}

(* {0., 3059.73} *)
```

For a common scale but displaying only tailored portions of the scale,

```
Partition[
  Table[
   DensityPlot[f[r, B, z], {r, 0, 10}, {z, -5, 5},
    FrameLabel -> {r, z}, PlotLabel -> StringForm["B = ``", B],
    ColorFunction -> (ColorData["SunsetColors"][(# - min)/(max - min)] &),
    ColorFunctionScaling -> False,
    PlotPoints -> 250,
    PlotLegends -> Automatic,
    ImageSize -> 300],
   {B, {0, 5, 10, 25}}], 2] // Grid
```

[image]

For identical scales,

```
Partition[
  Table[
   Legended[
    DensityPlot[f[r, B, z], {r, 0, 10}, {z, -5, 5},
     FrameLabel -> {r, z}, PlotLabel -> StringForm["B = ``", B],
     ColorFunction -> (ColorData["SunsetColors"][(# - min)/(max - min)] &),
     ColorFunctionScaling -> False,
     PlotPoints -> 250,
     ImageSize -> 300],
    BarLegend[{"SunsetColors", {min, max}}]],
   {B, {0, 5, 10, 25}}], 2] // Grid
```

[image]